# what does mean for this error "Notice: Array to string conversion in line 96"

Tags: php-7

this is the example of signup page. the error is"Notice: Array to string conversion in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\signup.php on line 96" what are the possible solutions.

here is the code........

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root') or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($con,'kms') or die (mysqli_error());
if (isset($_POST['techno']) && isset($_FILES['profile_picture']))
{

$firstname =        $_POST['firstname'];
$middlename =       $_POST['middlename'];
$lastname =         $_POST['lastname'];
$email =            $_POST['email'];
$password =         $_POST['password'];
$psw_repeat =       $_POST['psw_repeat'];
$dob =              $_POST['dob'];
$gender =           $_POST['gender'];
$occupation =       $_POST['occupation'];
$address =          $_POST['address'];
$about =            $_POST['about'];
$phonenumber =      $_POST['phonenumber'];
$profile_picture =  $_FILES['profile_picture'];

$q = "INSERT INTO user (firstname,middlename,lastname,email,password,dob,gender,occupation,address,about,phonenumber,profile_picture) values ('$firstname','$middlename','$lastname','$email','$password',$dob,'$gender','$occupation','$address','$about',$phonenumber,'$profile_picture')";

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["profile_picture"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["profile_picture"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["profile_picture"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_picture"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["profile_picture"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}


 if($psw_repeat != $password)
{
echo("Password does not match");
}
mysqli_query($con,$q) or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_close($con);

}
?>
```

in line number 96...the code is for inserting data into database...
i have googled this error....ut there is no solution

Comment: `$_FILES['profile_picture']` is an array, it makes little sense to try and insert that into the `profile_picture` column. Plus you are _moving_ the uploaded file to a different location, so that _new_ location is probably what you should insert to begin with, because the temporary location of the uploaded file does you no good later on anyway.

Comment: actually i didn't get you...please be more specific

Comment: What exactly didn’t you get?